# Displaying dynamic kanban colors according to record state in OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo

could someone tell me in what way I can display the items in a view kanban with a specific color according to the state that is the record.

I'm trying something like this

```
<div t-attf-class="#{record.state=='scheduled' ? oe_kanban_color_#{kanban_getcolor(1)} : oe_kanban_color_#{kanban_getcolor(0)}">
```

but I looked ALL elements and not only those who are in the "scheduled".

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have copy/pasted exactly what you typed in the view definition, then your `t-attf- class` attribute is malformed, and all record will have the following class:

```
class="#{record.state=='scheduled' ? oe_kanban_color_1 : oe_kanban_color_0"
```

which, due to CSS class precedence, will cause them all to have the `oe_kanban_color_1` style.

A few hints:

- To avoid coloring some records, you can omit the `oe_kanban_color_X` entirely in some cases
- You can use a `t-att-class` attribute to allow arbitrary Javascript expressions, depending on what you want to do. In contrast, `t-attf-class` only allows replacing placeholders.
- When comparing field values with Javascript operators you normally want to use the `value`  or `raw_value` of the field, rather that the Field object itself. `value` will only differ from `raw_value` when the value needs specific rendering, such as dates, numbers, etc.
- The `kanban_getcolor()` function accepts any integer or string and returns one of the 10 default kanban color indexes.

Based on the above, the following might be closer to what you tried to do (note the **`t-att-class`** attribute:

```
<div t-att-class="record.state.value == 'scheduled' ?
                  'oe_kanban_color_1' :
                  'oe_kanban_color_0' ">
```

Alternatively, you could use `t-attf-class` and let `kanban_getcolor()` pick a color based on the state string:

```
<div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_color_#{kanban_getcolor(record.state.value)}">
```

That last example is similar to what is done in many default kanban views in the official OpenERP distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information!, Was very useful. Thanks to your help can understand and fix the problem I had.